# Getting class cast expression while evaluating the spring integration expression

Tags: java, spring, casting, spring-integration, spring-el

I am getting class cast exception while compiling below expression with Spring Integration.

**Exception :**

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No
>   converter found capable of converting from type java.lang.Class to
>   type java.lang.String

**Expression:**

```
<int:transformer expression=
        "((#{T(my.package.exceptions.MyCustomException)})
payload.getCause()).getMyCustomStringAssociatedWithExceptionInstance()" />
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast with SpEL (it's not Java); but you don't need to - you can simply use

```
expression="payload.cause.myCustomStringAssociatedWithExceptionInstance"
```

Magic!

You can use explicit getters too, but SpEL will use them implicitly.